# Mod re-write forward empty directory and convert paths to parameters

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I currently use this to move from `example.com/nodirectory` where there is no directory to `example.com/user?user=nodirectory` where this is a `user` directory:

```
RewriteCond %{LA-U:REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{LA-U:REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /user/index.html?user=$1 [QSA,L,R=301]
```

I am trying to extend this so that a URL `example.com/nodirectory/value1` would end up as `example.com/user?user=nodirectory&param1=value1`

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /user/index.html?user=$1&param1=$2[QSA,L,R=301]
```

The above just cause too many redirects.

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html it is on this page.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{LA-U:REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

Should be

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

Because the rule is in a htaccess file, the first directive would work if it were in the httpd.conf file.